# On webview back button of webview is not navigating to previous activity/page

Tags: android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/agVSw.png)I am using a webview on a activity on that webview there is one back button (not a backpress button on keyboard) which is tappable but it's not working.Any Idea how to handle this click of webview buttons.

CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
        cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);

```
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
      ProgressDialog progressDialog =
          ProgressDialog.show(activity, Constants.EMPTY_VALUE, Constants.PLEASE_WAIT, true);

      public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url, headers);
        return true;
      }

      public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {

        if (activity != null && progressDialog != null) {
          progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        }

        updatePaymentUrl = null;
        if (url.contains("callback-data")) {
          webView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          showpDialog();
          int indexQ = url.indexOf("?");
          partUrl = url.substring(indexQ + 1, url.length());
          speedOrderUpdateApi();
        }

        if (updatePaymentUrl != null) {
          super.onPageStarted(view, updatePaymentUrl, favicon);
        } else {
          super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }
      }

      public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description,
          String failingUrl) {
        Logger.logInfo("errorCode = ", String.valueOf(errorCode));
        Logger.logInfo("description = ", description);
        Logger.logInfo("failingUrl = ", failingUrl);
        super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
      }

      @Override
      public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        if (activity != null && progressDialog != null) {
          if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
          }

          // If title not found hide webview
          Logger.logInfo("view.getTitle() = ", view.getTitle());
          if (view.getTitle() != null && "Not Found".equals(view.getTitle())) {
            view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            Toast.makeText(activity, "Link Not Found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          }
        }
      }
    });

    // Not needed
    Random random = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
    int randomNumber = random.nextInt();
    Logger.logInfo("urlTemp = ", url);
    webView.loadUrl(url, headers);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

`WebView` doesn't have `OnBackPress` by default and we use `onKeyDown` instead for going to previous page, here is example, you can put this code in your `WebView` activity

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown (int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && webView.canGoBack()) {

        webView.goBack(); // go back in only the web view
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

**Update:**

put this code in `onClick()` for that button

```
if(webView.canGoBack()){
       webView.goBack();
    } else {
      finish();
    }
```

Comment: No..This is not a solution ... onKeyDown() button is working fine but on webView I have one BACK text button I need handle that.U can see attached image.

Comment: No this is not a answer I think I should write a code inside onPagefinished() of webView.client().

Answer (score 0):

You can use `WebView.addJavaScriptInterface()` to communicate from your web page to native code,

For these you will have to create a `WebInterface` (name it anything you want) and add it as a `JavascriptInterface` to your `WebView`,

for e.g

```
public class YourWebInterface {

    private Context context;

    public YourWebInterface(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void goBack() {
        if(webView.canGoBack()){
           webView.goBack();
        } else {
          finish();
        }
    }
}
```

Now add this interface to your webview as

```
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new YourWebInterface(context), "Android");
```

now in your webpage you can call this method using the `Android` object that we are passing with the `Interface`,

for exmaple on your button click in webpage you can do something like this :

`Android.goBack()`